# wxPython MenuBar causes weird initial layout

Tags: wxpython

I'm using wxPython (Phoenix) on Python 3. My current code:

```
import wx

class GUI(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, title):
    super(GUI, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(-1, -1))
    self.ini_gui()
    self.Show()

def ini_gui(self):
    self.status_bar = self.CreateStatusBar() 
    main_panel = wx.Panel(self)
    filemenu = wx.Menu() 
    menu_open = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, 'Open', 'Open a file')
    menu_about = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, 'About', 'About...')

    menubar = wx.MenuBar()
    menubar.Append(filemenu, "File")
    # self.SetMenuBar(menubar) # !!!CAUSE WEIRD LAYOUT!!!

    vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    selection_area = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    game_label = wx.StaticText(main_panel, label='Select a game')
    selection_area.Add(game_label, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=8)
    gamelist = ['A', 'B']
    self.game_combobox = wx.ComboBox(main_panel,
                                size=wx.DefaultSize, choices=gamelist)
    selection_area.Add(self.game_combobox)
    vbox.Add(selection_area, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)
    main_panel.SetSizer(vbox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    GUI(None, title='Demo')
    app.MainLoop()
```

The window will look like this:

[image: Expected layout]

But when I add a MenuBar (uncomment line 18 `self.SetMenuBar(menubar)`), initially the window will look like this:

[image]

They layout only gets back to normal if I resize the window, or maximize it.

What is the problem of my code? **How do I make the window with the MenuBar appear correctly the first time?** like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the line

```
self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
```

to the end of ini_gui fixes it for me.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Do you know why it behaves that way?

Comment: Something to do with the order in which the sizers are layed out, another way that works while leaving the rest of the code as it was, is to put main_panel.Layout() at the end of ini_gui to coax main_panel to layout its controls

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `size` of the window bigger in your code :

```
super(GUI, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(-1, -1))
```

to :

```
super(GUI, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(400,200))
```

This will remove your problem of resizing each time the program runs.